# NGRX Effects: Dispatch multiple actions individually

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have the following effect:

```js
  @Effect()
  bookingSuccess$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(BookingActionTypes.BOOK_SEAT_SUCCESS),
    map((action: BookSeatSuccess) => action.payload.userUuid),
    switchMap(userUuid => [
      new SetConfirmation({confirmationType: ConfirmationType.Booking}),
      new GetAllBookings({floorId: this.configService.getSelectedFloorId()}),
      new HighlightUser({highlightedUser: userUuid})
    ])
  );
```

My goal is that the last action is dispatched with a delay.

Unfortunately putting it in it's own switchMap does not work, at least not like this, because then everything gets delayed:

```js
@Effect()
  bookingSuccess$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(BookingActionTypes.BOOK_SEAT_SUCCESS),
    map((action: BookSeatSuccess) => action.payload.userUuid),
    switchMap(userUuid => {
      // DOES NOT WORK, BECAUSE NOW ALL ACTIONS ARE DELAYED 5s
      return of(new HighlightUser({highlightedUser: userUuid})).pipe(delay(5000));
    }
    switchMap(() => [
      new SetConfirmation({confirmationType: ConfirmationType.Booking}),
      new GetAllBookings({floorId: this.configService.getSelectedFloorId()})
    ])
);
```

How can I dispatch multiple actions and handle one differently/async with a delay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can instead of an array return `merge` (the static variant) and then turn each action into an Observable and just delay the last one with `delay()`.

```
switchMap(userUuid => merge(
  of(new SetConfirmation({confirmationType: ConfirmationType.Booking})),
  of(new GetAllBookings({floorId: this.configService.getSelectedFloorId()})),
  of(new HighlightUser({highlightedUser: userUuid})).pipe(
    delay(1000),
  ),
)),
```